# Cannot resolve method error

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Please tell me what is wrong with my code? .setPositiveButton method is throwing me redline error. It cannot read smsText. I tried to declared smsText as public too but yet the problem is same.

```
public class PrepaidSMSBase extends Activity {

private String smsNumber = "";
private String smsPackageName;
private String smsPrice;
private String smsTitle;
private String smsText;


public PrepaidSMSBase(){}

public void setSmsPackageInformation(String smsTitle, String smsPackageName, String smsPrice, String smsNumber, String smsText)
{
    this.smsTitle = smsTitle;
    this.smsPackageName = smsPackageName;
    this.smsPrice = smsPrice;
    this.smsNumber = smsNumber;
    this.smsText = smsText;

}

public void activeSMSPackage()
{
    try
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrepaidSMSBase.this);
        builder.setTitle(smsTitle);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to active" + PrepaidSMSBase.this.smsPackageName + "in RS: " +
                PrepaidSMSBase.this.smsPrice);
        builder.setPositiveButton(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please click send button to activate desire Package", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: import all required classes. OnClickListener() should be of parent DialogInterface. Also import DialogInterface

Comment: problem is still exixt

Comment: Whats the error description of "reline"?

Answer (score 0):

There is not `setPositiveButton` with only one argument. As you can see in the documentation there are two methods `setPositiveButton` both with two arguments:

[public AlertDialog.Builder setPositiveButton (int textId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setPositiveButton(int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener))

[public AlertDialog.Builder setPositiveButton (CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setPositiveButton(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener))

Change your code like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrepaidSMSBase.this);
builder.setTitle(smsTitle);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to active" + PrepaidSMSBase.this.smsPackageName + "in RS: " +
        PrepaidSMSBase.this.smsPrice);
builder.setPositiveButton("Button text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please click send button to activate desire Package", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```